# Spark DataFrame convert milliseconds timestamp column in string format to human readable time with milliseconds

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a **Spark DataFrame** with a **timestamp column in milliseconds** since the epoche. The **column** is a **string**. I now want to transform the column to a **readable human time but keep the milliseconds.**
For example:

**1614088453671 -> 23-2-2021 13:54:13.671**

Every example i found transforms the timestamp to a normal human readable time without milliseconds.

What i have:

```
+------------------+
|epoch_time_seconds|
+------------------+
|1614088453671     |
+------------------+
```

What i want to reach:

```
+------------------+------------------------+
|epoch_time_seconds|human_date              |
+------------------+------------------------+
|1614088453671     |23-02-2021 13:54:13.671 |
+------------------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time before the milliseconds can be obtained using `date_format from_unixtime`, while the milliseconds can be obtained using a modulo. Combine them using `format_string`.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "human_date",
    format_string(
        "%s.%s",
        date_format(
            from_unixtime(col("epoch_time_seconds")/1000),
            "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        ),
        col("epoch_time_seconds") % 1000
    )
)

df2.show(false)
+------------------+-----------------------+
|epoch_time_seconds|human_date             |
+------------------+-----------------------+
|1614088453671     |23-02-2021 13:54:13.671|
+------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Attaching the modulo was what i was missing, couldn´t find the trick anywhere :)

Comment: Same! This is so crazy this is as complicated as it is